# Android tile Background "Failed to parse file"

Tags: android, parsing, background, tile

I used this Code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@drawable/backrepeat"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >
```

in my layoutfile

and this in backrepeat.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/mainmenu_background" 
android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

But in the Graphical Layout i get the following Error:

```
Failed to parse file [...]res\drawable\backrepeat.xml
```

What i am doing wrong ? Im using the Android 2.3.3 Library.

Comment: More stack trace will help in identifying the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a drawable named mainmenu_background. This can be an image (/res/drawable/mainmenu_background.png), a nine-patch image (/res/drawable/mainmenu_background.9.png) or defined in XML ( /res/drawable/mainmenu_background.xml). The file name mustn't contain upper cased letter or any special character except underscore(_).

Comment: I already had this files, but i found a fix for the Problem.

I just copied the files from "android-sdk\platform-tools" to the "android-sdk\tools" folder and it was fixed.